# Performing linear trend analysis within shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time-series

I have a shapefile (or several shapefiles, one per year, that I was going to join together to get all of the data in one attribute table) with an attribute for surface water area for each year. So like this:
area_2000, area_2001, ..., area_2015; each year with about 2 million objects/rows.

I was hoping to do a linear trend time series analysis in ArcGIS Desktop to get the slope, p-value, etc. as additional attributes for each object. I have used ArcGIS Desktop before to do regression analysis, but this time I want to do time series to get the trend in area for each object.

Is there a tool that would support this?

Comment: How is this different to regression analysis?

Comment: As I understand it the regression analysis in Arc looks at how multiple factors (represented by shapefiles) might predict a dependent variable (also another shapefile layer). I am just looking to get a trend across time. Maybe I can use the standard regression analysis tools but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I could do that.

Comment: ESRI dos support this type of analysis. Also, please provide more information on your desired analysis. A trend analysis is different than a multivariate temporal model. What is your dependent variable and what distributional form does it take?

Comment: Sorry; "does not support"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has no GIS component, but anyway. I ran this field calculator expression:

```
import numpy as np
x=[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005]
def getSlope(y):
 a,b=np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
 return a
#----------------
getSlope([ !Y_2001!, !Y_2002!, !Y_2003!, !Y_2004!, !Y_2005!])
```

on the field "SLOPE" in below table:

[image]

To get a slope of a trend. Look at numpy functions closely.

Comment: Thank you Felix. I think I will use this as inspiration and do the math in arcpy. I had just wanted to see if there was a built in Arc function to do this before I tried to write it in arcpy.